# how to simplify code documentation process - visual studio C#

Tags: c#, documentation

I'm wondering if there is any shortcut in visual studio to generate automatic documentation for a method or class.

For example when I write a method:

```
public void MyFunction(int d)
{

}
```

I want generate the following structure:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d"></param>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what happens when you type `///`  above the method signature.

You can also install and use a documentation tool like [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/GhostDoc/) that also adds some detail to the code documentation that it generates.

Comment: so obvious that I couldn't find the answer anywhere :)

Comment: Great. Thanks for this. I used only "///" and had no idea about GhostDoc

Comment: unfortunately Visual Studio Express Edition doesn't support ad-ins so I cannot use GhostDoc

Answer (score 4):

I use [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) for this. Means you can right-click on a method and it will insert the comments. The main benefit is that it inserts some default comment text as well, which is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my addin, [Atomineer Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/). It's similar to GhostDoc, but is considerably more powerful and flexible.